# CSS Adjacent Selector not working

Tags: css, css-selectors, operators

I am looking to create a CSS adjacent selector that does the following:

Selects all unordered lists `<ul>` that are preceded by a `strong` tag wrapped in a `p` tag.

So if I had the following HTML structure:

```
<p><strong>Headline</strong></p>
<ul>
    <li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

I would this this would work like so: `p strong + ul{}`

But it does not. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

The `ul` is a sibling of the `p`, not the `strong`:

```
   p   + ul
strong | li
```

That's why your selector doesn't work.

The problem here is that you can't use CSS to select a `p` only if it has a `strong`, making this impossible with a pure CSS selector. (And before anyone asks, it's probably not possible with the subject selector in Selectors 4 either.)

You'll need to find another way, e.g. giving `p` the appropriate class name, or by using JavaScript to traverse the DOM.

Comment: Could he remove the strong tags from the html, add a class to the p tag to preserve styling, and then use p + ul {}?

Comment: I could, but given my situation, I have a site with 200+ pages already using strong tags, so it wouldn't be an efficient process